# How to expose child component's @inputs and @outputs implicitly to grandparent in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, inheritance, angular-material

**Overview:**

Im just trying to understand the correct way to handle this scenario. Say I want to
create a custom version of a component (say a fruit select element) using an existing component (say `mat-select`). Now say the existing component exposes a bunch of `@inputs` and `@outputs` which my component doesn't "re-expose" to it's own consumers.

What if there were now apps that wanted to use my custom components but also wanted to use the "bottom" component's `@inputs/@outputs` ?

Here is an example of what Im trying to convey:

[image]

In this example say i've created `FruitSelect` component that is composed of a `MatSelect` + `some custom behavior around it`. But for this example I've intentionally not exposed the `placeholder` `@Input` exposed by `MatSelect`.

How does an app that wants to use `FruitSelect` in their view get to specify a `placeholder`?

**Options that I could come up with:**

1. Go thru the `MatSelect` class and manually re-expose all `@Inputs` and `@Outputs`. For the `@Outputs` I'll have to write wrapper methods that just propagate the events out.
2. Make my `FruitSelect` *extend* `MatSelect` , so it implicitly has access to it's `super`'s interactors. While this seems design-wise the first solution that comes to mind, not sure if it is easily doable. Googling didnt show a lot of people doing this, so not sure.

Comment: What did you end up doing here? I'm coming from React, trying to learn Angular. In React this would be easy and a normal approach, but how do you solve this in Angular? Are we not supposed to wrap components in new components?

Comment: ` wrap components in new components` - pretty much :(

Answer (score 2):

So, as far as i see you have 2 options that you described. From my experience, i can say that **I saw component inheritance in use only once**, it has a lot of drawbacks - it brings **another level of complexity (huge)**, **it doesn't inherits template**, and check what **you will inherit** from [MatSelect](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/391a9fd5b72780192ef952140d74711424dfda81/src/lib/select/select.ts#L226) into your child component (**~30 public fields**).

---

So in **case of inheritance**, you will end up with component that has a **lot of meaningless fields** inside + you will **still need to bind all the outputs** to inherited event triggers (again **because template is not being inherited**).

---

On the other hand, you need so far only **placeholder** input, so you can just **re-expose it**. It also makes sense for your component, but not all the **MatSelect** fields have meaning for **FruitSelect**, so **you can select which ones** you want to re-expose.

---

Speaking about **my opinion**, i would definitely prefer second option (**re-exposing**). Hope that helps.